# Showing that the set $\{e^{-x}: x > 0, x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is neither open or closed rigourously.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I want to show that the set $\{e^{-x}: x > 0, x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is neither open or closed rigourously. I have the idea intuitively which I will describe for each scenario below, but before that two definitions:

> **Defn 1):** A set $A$ is said to be open if there exists an $\epsilon$ -neighbourhood around every point $x \in A$ s.t $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset A$
>
> **Defn 2):** A set $A$ is said to be closed if the set $A$ contains all of its limit points.

**Proof Idea**

i) not open:

If you draw the graph of $f(x) = e^{-x}$ you get the inverse exponential function. Now picking any point on this graph you can "see" that any $\epsilon$- neighbourhood around a point will contain points not in the set, in particular any point to the left or right of the point $x \in \{e^{-x}: x > 0, x\in \mathbb{R}\}$

ii) not closed:

This one I am a little bit more shakey on. The point $0$ is in the set if you take the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$, but if you take $x \rightarrow 0$ you head towards $+\infty$. I'm not sure how to classify this. Since this set extends over all of $\mathbb{R}$ I want to include it, but from past readings I think it might not be the case.

**My Problems**:  These are my ideas, so how would I make them rigourous? I can't think of anything more beyond this sort of paragraph form of explanation. Possibly I'm too caught up in wanting to use symbolic notation...

Comment: Observe that $\{\,e^{-x}\mid x>0,\Bbb x\in\Bbb R\,\}=(0,1)$. This is open as a subset of $\Bbb R$, but neither open nor closed as a subset of $\Bbb C$. I do not know what you want to show.

Comment: Actually I didn't know that $\{\,e^{-x}\mid x>0,\Bbb x\in\Bbb R\,\}=(0,1)$....that makes things alot easier to work with, but now out of curiosity where could I find a proof of this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For not open, your proof does not work because you just have the points in $\Bbb R$, not the points $(x,f(x))$ in $\Bbb R^2$.  Can you represent the set in a much simpler way?  What is the range of the function?   In fact the set is open.

For not closed, you want to find a limit point not in the set.  $1$ works because of the restriction $x \gt 0$.  Find a sequence in the set that converges to $1$.

Comment: With regards to your hint, this was actually something I was trying to wrestle with in regards to interpretation. So the "points" that I am analyzing explicitly are **only** the points from the set? i.e only the values that are obtained when I take a real number and plug it into the function $e^{-x}$? So the reals that i use to plug into the function themselves are not considered then?

Comment: That is correct.  The set is just the set of values taken by $e^{-x}$ as $x$ ranges over $(0,\infty)$.  It is a subset of $\Bbb R$

Comment: Do you know of a proof somewhere close at hand that I can look at to examine the equality of my set to $(0,1)$. Really curious now.

Comment: It is one of those things "too simple to bother proving", one of the properties of the exponential function.  Given any number $y$ in $(0,1)$ you can find an $x \gt 0$ so that $e^{-x}=y$  Note that I corrected my answer for closed to show that the points are one dimensional.

Comment: I do see your point with regards to "too simple to prove". I don't know why I never thought of thinking about these sets in this one dimensional fashion, it's blown my mind and made things a lot easier to reconcile. Thanks for the help.